# Failed absolute import

Tags: python

I have created a test that looks like this:

```
import pytest
from datetime import date

from task import task_cm

@pytest.fixture
def setup_database():
    db = task_cm.SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
    db.task_insert_new(name='Today task',description="Test of description",deadline=date.today)
    db.task_insert_new(name='Tommorow Task',deadline=date.today+1)
    yield db

def test_connetion(setup_database):
    con = setup_database
    assert len(list(con.execute('SELECT * FROM tasklist'))) == 2
```

which is located in a structure that was recommended by [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery)

```
├── __init__.py
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── task
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── task_cm.py
├── test
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── task_cm_test.py
```

But when I try to run tests it fails with error:

```
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/task_cm_test.py:4: in <module>
    from task import task_cm
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'task'
```

I have read the whole Import module documentation and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: How do you run the test? did you use --import-mode?

Comment: @assli100 no, I was so focused on ImportError which combined with my lack of knowledge in pytest lead me to just to runing`pytest` instead of  `pythone3 -m pytest`...
Issue is resolved. Please create an answer, I will mark it as resolution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--import-mode` [flag](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html?highlight=pythonpath#) so it will take care of your `sys.path` while running the test, and will add the modules directories to it.